# Please stop bullying!

Tags: discussion

My recent posts have been suffering malicious close votes and downvotes from some users. Some of them are easy to find out from my closed posts.

Please stop bullying! 
Deriving mental pleasure from mistreating other people is a disease against humanity!

Do not encourage brutality and discrimination! It will destroy others' lives (you never know)!

Comment: How do you see into the minds of voters to claim that their intentions are "malicious"? Or that they derive "mental pleasure" from clicking an arrow?

Comment: Can you prove that their votes are benign and not seem random at all, and they suffer mental pain but still admirably cast those votes, and their incentives of mistreating other people is to give themselves mental pain?

Comment: No, it is not incumbent to me to prove the votes have any emotional quotient at all; *you* have asserted they are malicious, so the burden of proof falls to you. That is how it works.

Comment: There is no "proof" anywhere in your post. You are happy to play the victim, but feel no compunction baselessly accusing other people here of bad faith.

Comment: By the way, can you sound less erudite?  I have to google to know what you mean, or I just ignore your comments.

Comment: Tim, I'm finding these posts & comments lately all a bit worrying. Are you doing ok? It's just a meaningless Q&A site, the points don't matter.

Comment: @MichaelHomer It is not about reputation, you should know that already. It is about huge waste of  time and efforts, wrestling with meaningless bureaucratism created by power lovers and human torturers and attention seekers, worsening  already very bad situations...

Comment: Yeah, it's the "already very bad situations" that I'm concerned about and that they're getting worse. Are you all right? Nothing on this site is actually important. Just take care, ok.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Thanks for asking. If I am all right, would I have so much time spending here trying to improve my knowledge?

Answer (score 19):

This is not a solution of your issues with downvotes. Just my thoughts on the issue.

You are asking a lot of questions, so due to that, you would expect to get numerically more downvotes and closures overall than anyone just asking the occasional question.

That is, if your questions were average, but they are not.

Your questions are sometimes *very* similar to each other, with only minor details varying (such as with your most recent server-related questions), and they often try to pin down details that most users would deem uninteresting or unimportant, and sometimes these details are bordering to philosophical ponderings.  Also, you tend to ask questions *around* details until (I assume) you feel you understand the whole context (this also applies to your server-related questions of the last 24 hours or so).

In principle, I have no issues with this, but I'm assuming that some users have.  It doesn't help that this is what we, at the same time, suggest to many users.  "If you have additional questions about *whatever it is*, ask a new question".

Ideally, people would not downvote questions that they don't understand the technical details of or read properly, and ideally they don't look at who's asking when deciding to downvote or vote for closures.  But then again, people are people, and each user approach this differently.