# Watch out for hateful languages?

Tags: discussion

What I described here have happened multiple times from users with particular powerful privileges, though not recently. Inspired by that "Leave and go back to your country if you don't like this place" is so hateful, how do you think about "Leave this site and find some other place if you don't follow the rules" which might well be individual interpretations? Last but not least,  that has been said to   user who has been around since much earlier historically.  If you can think of this site as your home, others can  think the same and could have thought so much earlier.

Comment: "Go back to your country" and "Leave if you don't follow the rules" are not quite the same thing. Are you proposing that we simply scrap all rules of conduct on this site?  Also, if anyone considers this site as "their home", then I think they would benefit from taking a break from the computer for a while, seriously.

Comment: Depending on the country, it might very well mean *death* to return. Are you saying that using a site other than Stack Exchange is equivalent to death?

Answer (score 14):

Imagine a hotel that only offers beds made of nails. It is targeting people who like sleeping on nails, and bills this as their main feature: "Come test out our beds of nails! The most uncomfortable beds you've ever slept in at the cheapest prices!". Now, obviously, this isn't a hotel for everyone. I certainly wouldn't go there! But if I did choose to go there, perhaps out of curiosity, it would be ridiculous for me to then complain to the management because my bed was made of nails and I couldn't sleep!

In such a scenario, it makes perfect sense to for the management to tell me to go find another place that is more to my liking. To take a slightly less extreme example, consider a bar called "Heavy Metal Central" that always plays heavy metal music. It would be patently absurd if I were to go and complain because they don't play jazz. The only reasonable answer management could give me is "Go find a bar that plays Jazz, we do Metal here".

So, if you don't like the rules of a place *which you choose freely to go to and is only one of many available places*, then yes, you should find another place. One whose rules are closer to what you want. It is perfectly reasonable for people to tell you to go find another site when you take issue with the very things that define the site you are using.

You seem to consider [downvoting or closing questions abusive](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5130/22222), for example. The concepts of voting and closing are integral to the Stack Exchange model. They are fundamental aspects of the site's mechanics; the very things that make the site work and make it different to all the other sites and forums where you can ask questions about Unix and Linux. So if you consider these things abuse, then the only reasonable thing anyone can tell you is to find another place, one that is closer to your vision of how such a site should be.

On a final note, equating telling someone to leave the country they were born and/or raised in because they object to the direction their country's political establishment is taking to telling a user of an internet site to find another site instead is as insensitive as it is absurd. Come on!